Missing Data in Seasonal Time series. Problems with validation and pre-processing
I have daily data and my goal is to do a 14 day forecast of different product sales in retail. My question is rather about the data and the preprocessing than the models used for forecasting.
A frequent problem is the training and validation on missing data intervals. Let me give you an example:

In the course of three years this product has a few missing value intervals. This can have different reasons: Disruptions in the supply chain, the product wasn't even listed and therefore not sold at all, another very similar product being released and sold instead, shipments being late, stockouts, business decision to not list the product, etc...
I don't need Zero-Periods related to these factors in my forecast. These factors are either unforeseeable or are our own business decisions. The only zero Periods I need in my forecast are the ones based on yearly seasonality.
What I would normally do is simply doing train/test splits or cross-validation on the given data to find the best model I can fit and use this model.
My Problem with that is, I am validating (and training) the models on incomplete data. I often have the case that the forecasts are too low or that there are (close to) zero-periods in the forecast which are not part of a seasonal pattern. In practice this can be very costly in terms of lost sales.
I can see a problem especially when a zero-period is used for validation. Let me give a clear example. Same time series, but I've cut off the last 14 days. In a simple train/test split this would be my 14 Days of validation data:

In this rather extreme example a Model forecasting zero-values would have a great fit, but no benefit for my professional objective.
On the other hand there are products like this:

This Product has a clear obvious seasonality. In this case of course I need the seasonal zero-periods also in the forecast. A model actually forecasting what I want and need would get bad scores in the forecast measures.
I've already experimented with Interpolation to fill the non-seasonal gaps, but so far I had huge Issues making the interpolation methods respect the seasonality if present.

Is interpolation the right measure to tackle this issue?
If Interpolation is a valid choice, can you recommend Interpolation techniques and how do I even determine the timesteps I need to interpolate?
How Do I get to the point to where my forecasts measures actually depict accuracy in terms of what I am trying to achieve?
Are there other data-preprocessing tips you can give me?


If the are gaps in your data where the product was not sold for whatever reason, you could model that by using an additional variable which would indicate this (and the model would hopefully learn to use it). There isn't much you can do about cross validation, if the data is missing then it's missing. You might have to write your own loop to only evaluate on the periods which are of interest to you.

@user2974951 I've tried adding a exogenous variable which is
0 when the timestamp is 0 and
1 when the timestamp is >0.
Sadly It only improved the models by a very small amount.

@user2974951 Even if the variable would work and lets imagine I would get 100% accuracy. The forecast is still not depicting what I actually need.
Seems like I am optimizing something that doesnt fullfill the use-case. If there is a stockout or a late shipment, somebody will set the forecast to 0 manually with his domain knowledge. I am not sure I made that point clear enough in the question.

Welcome to the lovely world of retail forecasting. You could write an entire book on these topics. Or buy software from people who do this for a living, and have done so for years (SCNR).
First off, I would actually not work with predictors to mark zero sales, but cut periods out from the training set where we do not want to learn from the observed data - which will often mean long periods of zero sales, but also others, e.g., if you have nonzero sales but stockouts. Yes, that means that autoregressive or MA components may have a hard time. I personally do not find these useful in retail forecasting in the first place.
I would absolutely not use interpolation, or any other kind of imputation. These simulate knowledge we simply don't have. If you never sold fresh regional strawberries outside their season, then you shouldn't pretend you know how they would have sold just to fool your model.
Next, you need to be careful with evaluation, and this can mean different things. If you have data you "don't want to learn from" per above, you very likely don't want to evaluate on it, either. But that's just a start. Especially for seasonal or weather-related sales, you may be very interested in getting the timing right. If you are off on when the first nice weekend in summer is, then everybody will have bought their new lawn furniture from a competitor by the time your model pushes product into the store. In your examples, it might make sense to evaluate on the tail end of valid sales, which would be different per series. (Automatic detection of valid or invalid sales is a topic by itself.)
So I would argue you first need to figure out what you are forecasting for, i.e., the "what you want" you refer to, which can mean different things. Operational store replenishment from a central DC will need quite different forecasts than original ordering into the DC at much larger volumes and on completely different time scales.

I understand that there are concerns with imputation, but I dont think I quite understood what the problems are. If you have another striking example I would be very grateful. The explanation you kindly provieded:"If you never sold fresh regional strawberries outside their season, then you shouldn't pretend you know how they would have sold just to fool your model." I dont fully understand. My thought was to imputate only the not season related zero-periods.

Cutting out the non-seasonal zero periods from training and evaluation is a thought that never crossed my mind. Thanks!

The case is indeed less clear for "supply chain issues related" zero periods. But even then, I would say the burden of proof is on people who argue for imputation. How should our model be improved by using a different model to impute data that we then learn from? That aside, your series are extremely well behaved. If your problematic time periods happen during promotions (where we typically have higher sales, higher variance and fewer observations), your imputation can have a major impact on the model... and still be based essentially on hope.

To be honest I am pretty surprised to hear that I need to figure out what I am forecasting for. Not that I am not grateful, I'm just surprised.
I am forecasting the demand of different SKU's on a daily granularity with a 14 day horizon. The forecast is calculated and updated every day.
Isn't that the answer?

Heh. You might find that chapter in our textbook interesting. Why do you forecast like that? It does not address replenishment (because for that you need quantile forecasts, not expectations, for safety amounts). It's not for workforce planning (where you need forecasts not per SKU, but on an aggregate level). It's not for promotion planning (where you need forecasts for the entire promotion runtime, and across stores and often SKUs). Yes, I very much believe it makes sense to figure out why we are forecasting before we dig into it. For one, it may show us where to focus our improvements.

Fancy a spontaneous trip to France? I will be giving a workshop around exactly this kind of topics on Sunday at the International Symposium on Forecasting in Dijon: https://isf.forecasters.org/program/workshops/

Sorry, I know what information was missing all along.
I am forecasting the demand of the SKU's to feed a connected Order Optimization Algorithm. If I understand the term correctly that would fall under replenishment.
Do you have a reference/source that adresses replenishment? The link you proviede to the book is versy interesting, but as you already mentioned it doesn't adress replenishment.

The workshop sounds like exactly what I need, but sadly that won't be possible

Very good. Then your requirements are likely determined by that algorithm. I certainly hope it requires more than just expectation forecasts... because, for one, variances in retail also vary quite a bit. Your order-up-to levels should really be governed by quantile forecasts over lead times, but you will also need more forecasts once you start optimizing orders: any fillup should take into account how quickly you will sell off the fillup amounts. Better not to fill up with product that has a high forecast over the next week just because of a promotion!
